# how to print a string with numbers in r

Tags: r, string, printing

I have two vectors that i am calculating mean and sd for and i want to print the results in a separate line for each vector

```
t1<-c(37.96, 37.67,  32.29, 37.67, 38.52, 38.52, 37.67, 38.24, 36.54, 41.07, 38.81, 33.71, 37.11, 45.89)
t2<-c(51.84, 49.57, 46.45, 50.14, 50.42, 52.4, 49, 49, 49.57, 53.54, 49.57, 46.17, 50.14, 57.22)
mean(t1)
sd(t1)
mean(t2)
sd(t2)
```

The result should be

> 37.97643±3.127839
>
> 50.35929±2.801649

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sprintf`:

```
sprintf("%f±%f", mean(t1), sd(t1))
# [1] "37.976429±3.127839"

sprintf("%f±%f", mean(t2), sd(t2))
# [1] "50.359286±2.801649"
```

Comment: How do you print a "+-" sign like that?

Comment: @RichardScriven, copy and paste and hope it works :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `cat`:

```
cat (mean(t1),"±",sd(t2),"\n")
# [1] 37.97643 ± 2.801649 

cat (mean(t2),"±",sd(t2),"\n")
# [1] 50.35929 ± 2.801649
```

Comment: `cat` works too (+1). I prefer that you can store the output of `sprintf` though, hence my recommendation. `paste` would also work.